# Append, Sort, Store and Retrieve an HTML List with HTML Storage

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery .sortable and .append to allow for an html list. I am trying to utilize local html storage to then save the list. The list is not being stored.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable">
</ul>

<form id="append" action="">
  <input type="text" id="appendvalue">
  <input type="submit" value="Append">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});

$( "#append" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $( "#sortable" ).append( "<li id=\"storevalue\" class=\"ui-state\">" + 
  $('#appendvalue').val() + "</li>" );

  event.preventDefault();   
}); 

// Store
localStorage.store_data = ("key", 
document.getElementById("storevalue").HTML);

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("storevalue").HTML = localStorage.store_data;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikestratton/u4uxtmm6/)

Comment: Please @Mike, let me know if my solution works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are adding the `#storevalue` item in your DOM only on `#append`'s submit event while you store it's content when javascript loads.

At this moment the `#storevalue` item still doesn't exists.

Moreover, if you want your data to persist through refreshes, use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`

Put the code to store that content inside `#append`'s submit listener

```
// Store
$("#append").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#sortable").append("<li id=\"storevalue\" class=\"ui-state\">" + 
    $('#appendvalue').val() + "</li>");

    sessionStorage.setItem("yourkey", $('#appendvalue').val());

});
```

And put the *"retrieve"* code in a button click listener

```
// Retrieve
$("#retrieve").click(function() {
    $("#sortable").append( "<li id=\"storevalue\" class=\"ui-state\">" + sessionStorage.getItem("yourkey") + "</li>" );
});
```

Here is [the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/gkwnzh2p/4/)

Comment: That did not solve the problem. You should be able to refresh the browser and see the appended data still there, as in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mikestratton/j2nkekbe/

Comment: I do appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Excuse me Mr, I don't know what is happening to jsfiddle on my pc, the link I posted is not the one who I edited, I'm rewriting it

Comment: @MikeStratton [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/gkwnzh2p/4/) should work as you need. Use sessionStorage instead of localStorage if you want your data to persist through refreshes

Comment: Could you please give my question a +1?